# How do I send command with parameters to external cmd application in Python?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I need to execute and send command to external app from python:

```
.\Ext\PrintfPC /p “C:\Leica\DBX” /l “.\joblist.log”
```

It is cmd app, Is it possible to hide its console and terminate after all also using only
python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html). Example for executing the `ls -l` bash command on a unix system:

```
subprocess.call(['ls', '-l'])
```

So, in your case it should probably look something like:

```
subprocess.call(['.\Ext\PrintfPC', '/p', 'C:\Leica\DBX', '/l', '.\joblist.log'])
```

Have a look at the linked documentation though, because you can also get the output back from the command line execution by using pipes / `Popen` objects.